# Protractor tests pipeline fail exit code 135 Error: Could not find update-config.json

Tags: protractor, webdriver

I have protractor test pipeline which fail with error 135 Could not find update-config.json.

That is the command which i use in update Webdriver task:

node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=77.0.3865.10

IF i am using that command the error is 199 about chrome version: node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update

Comment: Is anyone has an idea where is the problem

Comment: Uninstall protractor and delete node_modules/protractor, then try after reinstall.  Install other version if the former method can't work.  Another possibility, you use global protractor to run case, but update webdriver on local protractor.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem using version 12.1.6 of webdrive manager but now i hav another isuue all tests on my machine pass bu after run with the pipeline on azure devops the test fail with:

Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, h3)‌